# TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, typeerror

I am testing out NLTK and trying to train the punkttokenizer, I am trying  to get the GWBush-2005&6 state union speeches and I am getting the Lazycorpusloader is not callable.

Code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer

train_text = state_union("2005-GWBush.txt")
sample_text = state_union("2006-GWBush.txt")

custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)

def process_content():
    try:
        for i in tokenized:
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
            print tagged
    except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

process_content()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\smash_000\My Documents\Li-Clipse-Python\CodeTesting\blahblahblah\smallcodetesting.py", line 7, in <module>
    train_text = state_union("2005-GWBush.txt")
TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Because I am using python 2.7 its a bit diffrent. I have manually call words and then encode them to wither ascii or UTF-8 because its scraped from a website and generally is in a unicode format, thus requiring me to encode it.

here's the code snippit that is required.

```
train_text = nltk.corpus.state_union.words("2005-GWBush.txt")
sample_text = nltk.corpus.state_union.words("2006-GWBush.txt")

for words in train_text:
    train_text = words.encode("ascii")
for wordes in sample_text:
    sample_text = wordes.encode("ascii")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   from nltk.corpus import state_union
   nltk.download("state_union")
   nltk.download("averaged_perceptron_tagger")
  from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
  train_text = state_union.raw("2005-GWBush.txt")
  sample_text = state_union.raw("2006-GWBush.txt")

 custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

 tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)

def process_content():
try:
    for i in tokenized:
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        print(tagged)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

process_content()
```

Try this... use .raw to use the text data from state_union